# Python 2to3 Converted Python Package Does Not Find Script

Tags: linux, python3

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.5 installed in Debian Stretch on my 64bit Linux platform.

I have installed PyChem (http://pychem.sourceforge.net/), written in Python2 after converting the python files using the 2to3 script. There were no warning or error messages during the conversion process.

Installation put the files in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pychem` (with `pychem-1.0.egg-info` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`).

To test the application I tried:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
from pychem import pychem
from pychem.pychem import Chem
mol=Chem.MolFromSmiles("CC(oc1ccccC(O)=O)=O"
```

This generated the error message `No module named 'pychem'`.

Unfortunately, for me, the problem is beyond the very limited knowledge of computers I possess as an Organic Chemist. Pointers towards a solution to the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Is there a reason you wanted to convert the module to Python 3?

Comment: Amplifying @bertieb's point, your installation placed the files in the Python2.7 library, so you can't expect them to be found in Python3, if that is your default (`python -V` to verify). Try running the the test file with `python2`.